# I want to override the behavior when activating SelectionMode

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp

[image]

I have a simple GridView.
I want to override the behavior when activating SelectionMode. For example, change the location of the checkbox. How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set the [CheckMode](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates#inline-and-overlay-selection-visuals) property to specify whether the check box is shown using the inline style or overlay style to change the location of the checkbox in a `GridView`.

The `CheckMode` property is within the `ListViewItemPresenter` tag in a certain `ItemContainerStyle`, you can [make a copy of the default template](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates#listviewitempresenter) and modify only the properties(such as the `CheckMode` property) you need too. Otherwise, the visuals will probably not show up the way you expect because some properties won’t be set correctly.

If you need to change the position of the check box to other position or override other behavior about the check box, you can use [GridViewItemExpanded](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/item-containers-templates#expanded-xaml-item-templates) template which included with the default styles in **generic.xaml** to set a border named `MultiSelectSquare` in `ContentPresenter` tag.